# OPA policy to allow docker exec

Tags: docker, open-policy-agent, rego

I've deployed the OPA docker plugin as [per instruction](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/docker-authorization/). And everything was fine until I've tried to create custom docker API permissions for docker exec.

I've added following section to `authz.rego` file:

```
allow {
    user_id := input.Headers["Authz-User"]
    users[user_id].readOnly
    input.path[0] == "/v1.41/containers/busybox/exec"
    input.Method == "POST"
}
```

But it still gives me error when I try to run following bash command: `docker exec -it busybox sh` under `Bob` test user as per instruction.

`journalctl -u docker.service` provides following error:
`level=error msg="AuthZRequest for POST /v1.41/containers/busybox/exec returned error: authorization denied by plugin openpolicyagent/opa-docker-authz-v2:0.4: request rejected by administrative policy"`

The funny thing is when I comment out `input.path` section it works as full RW user so the rule works but the strict mention of API path - does not. Maybe I'm specifying it in a wrong way?

Tried different variations like:

```
input.path == ["/v1.41/containers/busybox/exec"]
input.path = ["/v1.41/containers/busybox/exec"]
input.path = ["/v1.41*"]
input.path = ["/v1.41/*"]
input.path = ["/v1.41%"]
input.path = ["/v1.41/%"]
```

Also would appreciate advice on how to allow `exec` operations for any container not only the specified one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, did you manage to resolve the issue ?  I use `input.Headers.Path`.  It is not working.  I wanted to restrict to certain user using `input.Body.User`, and is not working as well

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [input map](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/opa-docker-authz/blob/master/main.go#L155) provided to OPA, you should find both `input.Path`, `input.PathPlain` and `input.PathArr`:

```golang
input := map[string]interface{}{
    "Headers":    r.RequestHeaders,
    "Path":       r.RequestURI,
    "PathPlain":  u.Path,
    "PathArr":    strings.Split(u.Path, "/"),
    "Query":      u.Query(),
    "Method":     r.RequestMethod,
    "Body":       body,
    "User":       r.User,
    "AuthMethod": r.UserAuthNMethod,
}
```

There's no lowercase `input.path` available, but using any of the other alternatives should work.